# I put oil in the coolant by mistake in Chrysler 300c Hemi

Tags: coolant, chrysler-300c

I put a quart of oil in  the coolant compartment in my 300c Hemi Chrysler engine.  Can I drive it about 50 miles without hurting my engine to get my engine flushed?

Comment: That's a lot of oil, usually the expansion tank should be almost full, how did you manage to fill it? Either way, to my knowledge oil floats on many other liquids, so you can try sucking out as much as possible and then draining the coolant to replace with fresh one. Sure beats cooling your engine with oil and having to clean all of your cooling system.

Answer (score 3):

If you dumped the oil into the surge tank, you need to drain it before you run the engine. You could possibly run it without issue. The problem would be the cleanup. It comes down to cleaning the surge out only, or having to have the entire cooling system (radiator, engine block, reservoir, hoses, etc.) cleaned out, which is a *lot* of work.